# Saving lists to JSON on demand

Tags: python, json, list

```
def listsToFile(listName, listToSave):
    #Check if file exists : if the file does not exist, create it
    if(os.path.isfile('data.json') != True):
        dataFile = open("data.json", "w")
        data = {}
        json.dump(data, dataFile)
        dataFile.close()

    with open('data.json', 'r+') as readFile: 
        readData = json.load(readFile)
        
    readData[listName] = listToSave
    with open('data.json', 'r+') as outputToFile: 
        data = json.load(outputToFile)
        data.update(readData)
        outputToFile.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, outputToFile)
```

I'm having trouble with saving multiple python lists to a JSON using the code above.
When the code is run on a clean `data.json` file, or when the file hasn't yet been created, the code executes without issues.
If I run the code again after I've already created `data.json` file and filled it with necessary data, the code occasionally fails with the following error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2505 (char 2504)
```

Below is an example of a properly generated JSON file:

```
{"values1": [0.0, 0.9510565162951535, 0.5877852522924732, -0.587785252292473, -0.9510565162951536, 0.0, 0.9510565162951535, 0.5877852522924732, -0.587785252292473, -0.9510565162951536], "values2": [-0.005169993459294982, 0.900960478450234, 0.688082399145687, -0.6991548418279838, -0.7067674655652273, 0.02282072685197254, 1.0032296059350259, 0.264000562571027, -0.7222227190160149, -1.4026325206242891], "values3": [19.042863922620974, 37.87458461655387, 33.45043085989223, 4.620074671576601, 4.461864779721113, 19.62458304946258, 40.0, 24.636920062805316, 4.140664880521349, -10.0], "values4": [19.042863922620974, 37.37458461655387, 32.45043085989223, 3.1200746715766012, 2.461864779721113, 17.12458304946258, 37.0, 21.136920062805316, 0.1406648805213493, -14.5], "values5": [19.042863922620974, 37.37458461655387, 32.45043085989223, 3.1200746715766012, 84.0204012020356, 17.12458304946258, 37.0, 3.475329107497103, 75.8901259294412, 45.46783947206504], "values6": [19.042863922620974, 37.37458461655387, 32.45043085989223, 25.120074671576603, 106.0204012020356, 39.12458304946258, 59.0, 25.475329107497103, 75.8901259294412, 45.46783947206504]}
```

Below is an example of what happens when I run the code and try to save different lists to the already existing and filled `data.json` file:

```
{"values1": [0.0, 0.5877852522924731, 0.9510565162951535, 0.9510565162951536, 0.5877852522924732, 1.2246467991473532e-16, -0.587785252292473, -0.9510565162951535, -0.9510565162951536, -0.5877852522924734, 0.0, 0.5877852522924731, 0.9510565162951535, 0.9510565162951536, 0.5877852522924732, 1.2246467991473532e-16, -0.587785252292473, -0.9510565162951535, -0.9510565162951536, -0.5877852522924734], "values2": [-0.10117028598579918, 0.7779790908824286, 1.200393390118824, 1.0838219894046404, 0.15757602921920028, -0.0067210289946661814, -0.5273871827688272, -1.1565635352862502, -0.8323326253928102, -1.2756839944935217, -0.05004380182838799, 0.6714864299550243, 1.0662910625661586, 0.7590821618652706, 1.0445118435048915, -0.06508749032370621, -0.40940979225502727, -0.6795514583892261, -0.8884786917027516, -0.6762588207898561], "values3": [6.858612697312811, 15.735045460801214, 20.0, 18.823023449927092, 9.471074618060788, 7.812230479799041, 2.555264794781925, -3.797286587774387, -0.52365192768276, -5.0, 7.374817122860437, 14.659830065785634, 18.646020431489255, 15.544250444310677, 18.426124042177932, 7.222926792323841, 3.746437082519922, 1.0189206909381987, -1.090537141558372, 1.052165185030268], "values4": [5.781634685737641, 13.351407441895873, 19.0, 15.543929768576376, 13.69489283405558, 10.464760506006371, 0.3539527971091214, -8.5, -3.8334192237799343, -1.8576091755881983, 8.59357984630877, 8.034254186327477, 9.959064845492588, 13.037705232284743, 12.395566807169725, 1.0706082945977524, -2.3644898895249664, -8.913833863581623, -4.831138451105485, -6.463793291134955], "values5": [5.781634685737641, 13.351407441895873, 19.0, 15.543929768576376, 13.69489283405558, 30.782546604725596, 0.3539527971091214, -8.5, -3.8334192237799343, -1.8576091755881983, 38.0, 8.034254186327477, 9.959064845492588, 27.084472735684002, 12.395566807169725, 1.0706082945977524, -2.3644898895249664, -8.913833863581623, 2.9851725802192135, -6.463793291134955], "values6": [5.781634685737641, 13.351407441895873, 19.0, 37.543929768576376, 35.69489283405558, 52.782546604725596, 22.353952797109123, 13.5, -3.8334192237799343, -1.8576091755881983, 38.0, 8.034254186327477, 9.959064845492588, 27.084472735684002, 12.395566807169725, 1.0706082945977524, -2.3644898895249664, -8.913833863581623, 2.9851725802192135, -6.463793291134955]}955]}
```

As you can see, at the very end of the second JSON file, there is a junk value `955` and `]}` has been added.

The lists aren't added all at once. They are added one by one as each list is generated.
I am using JSON because I can later access all of the lists by their name.

Comment: This appears to be due to the updated data being shorter than the original data, thus not overwriting the entire file.  Calling `.truncate()` on the file after writing the new data will ensure there's nothing beyond that point left over.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, in hindsight it makes sense that there was some leftover data when adding shorter lists.
So far it works, haven't had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the seek call - it's overwriting the characters, but doesn't guarantee the file content is valid JSON

If your intention is to overwrite the file content with new JSON, then open the file in write mode

```
    with open('data.json', 'r+') as readFile: 
        readData = json.load(readFile)
        
    readData[listName] = listToSave
    data.update(readData)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outputToFile: 
        json.dump(data, outputToFile)
```